# How is induction on $p-q > 0$ used correctly here?

Tags: algebraic-topology, induction, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

I'm self learning Rotman's Algebraic topology and I've come across this theorem and proof.  I have two questions:

> $(1.)$  How did the author arrive at $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1}) = 0$ if $q+1 \ge n$?
>
> $(2.)$  How is induction used properly here?  Normally induction is done on a base case, $p=q$ in this example, and then assume it's true for $p-q = k$ and show that it's true for $p-q = k+1$.  But I don't see anywhere an expression of the form $p-q = k+1$ being shown to be true.  Can someone explain how induction is used here to show where $k+1$ is true?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the author explain it in the phrase: "for $p-(q+1) < p-q$"? The pair $(p,q+1)$ is the previous case to the pair $(p,q)$, in the sense that $p-(q+1)$ is one less than $p-q$.

Comment: So what was the point of saying $q \ge n \Rightarrow q+1 \ge n \Rightarrow H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})$ if  $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})$ is true immediately from the induction hypothesis?

Comment: You need $q+1 \ge n$ in order to use the inductive hypothesis.The pair being analyzed is $(p,q)$. The pair for which the inductive hypothesis is being applied is $(p',q') = (p,q+1)$. But you need to check that $(p',q')$ satisfies the prerequisites.

Comment: Could you explain why $q+1 \ge n$ is needed in order to use the inductive hypothesis?  I don't see how just $q+1 \ge n$ and not $n \gt p$ shows how either the left-most or right-most parts of the sequence are $0$.

Comment: The claim is that _if_  $(p,q)$ satisfy some conditions, then ... So to use the inductive hypothesis on $(p',q')$, not only must $p' - q'$ be less than $p-q$, but $(p',q')$ must also satisfy the specified conditions.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you're just assuming that $n \gt p$ and not $q \ge n$, you have $H_n((X^{q+1}, X^q) = 0$ by cellular filtration and $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1}) = 0$ because $p-(q+1) \lt p-q$ by induction.  If you're just assuming that $q \ge n$ and not $p \gt n$, why isn't it the case that $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})=0$ because, by induction, $p - (q+1) \lt p-q$?  What's wrong with that logic?  Why is it the case that $q+1 \ge n \Rightarrow H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})$ is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$(p',q') = (p,q+1)$$
where 
$$p-q >0,\;\;\text{and either}\;\;n > p\;\;\text{or}\;\;q \ge n$$
To apply the inductive hypothesis, you need to have
\begin{align*}
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;p'-q' \ge 0\\[4pt]
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;p'-q' < p-q\\[4pt]
&{\small{\bullet}}\;\;\text{either}\;\;n > p'\;\;\text{or}\;\;q' \ge n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Check the conditions one at a time . . .
\begin{align*}
&p-q > 0 \implies p-(q+1) \ge 0 \implies p'-q' \ge 0\\[4pt]
&p'-q'=p-(q+1) < p-q\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
To show $n > p'\;\;\text{or}\;\;q' \ge n$, consider two cases . . .

$\qquad$Case $(1)\,\!\!:\;n > p$.$\;\,$Then $n > p \implies n > p'$.

$\qquad$Case $(2)\,\!\!:\;q \ge n$.$\;\,$Then $q \ge n \implies q+1 > n \implies q' > n \implies q' \ge n$.

Thus, in each of the two cases, the requirements on $(p',q')$ are met.

Therefore the inductive hypothesis can be applied.

Comment: I don't understand.  The process of induction shows a base case is true, assumes it's true for some $k$, then shows that this implies it must be true for $k+1$.  In this example we have the base case being $p - q = 0$, or $p=q$, which has $H_n(X^p, X^p) = 0$ as true.  So we then assume that it's true for $p- q \gt 0$, or $p-q = k$ for some integer so that $H_n(X^p, X^q)=0$ where $p-q=k$.  But then we have to show that this implies that $H_n(X^p, X^q)$ where $p-q = k + 1$ is true.  Where in the proof given in the picture of the question does it show that the $k+1$ case is proven to be true?

Comment: This induction is best understood as going from $k-1$ to $k$. The pair $(p,q)$ satisfies $p-q=k$. The pair $(p',q')$ satisfies $p'-q'=k-1$. By the inductive hypothesis, after verifying the inequality conditions on $(p',q')$, the claim of the theorem is assumed to hold for the pair $(p',q')$. Based on the assumed truth of the theorem for the pair $(p',q')$, the exact sequence shows that the theorem holds for the pair $(p,q)$, which completes the induction.

Comment: If this induction is assuming $k-1$ and then showing $k$, then in what line of what paragraph of the picture included in the question does it show that $k$ is true?  In the third line of the second paragraph, it says $p-(q+1) \lt p-q$, so $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})$ by the induction hypothesis of $H_n(X^p, X^q)=0$ iff $p - q \gt 0$.  If we're assuming that $n \gt p$ and it is not the case that $q \ge n$, then $H_n(X^{q+1}, X^q)=0$ by cellular filtration.  Then $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})=0$  because $p-(q+1) \lt p - q$.  If $k = p - q$ is assumed by induction, then $p-(q+1)$ is less than $k$ and therefore...

Comment: ...$k-1$ is true inductively and $k+1$ isn't shown to be true.  This seems to take $k$ and show that $k-1$ is true and not $k+1$.  What is the specific flaw in the logic here?

Comment: I don't really see what bothers you. There's no $k+1$, just $k-1$ and $k$ (which is a perfectly valid alternate way to structure an induction). After verifying the base case $p-q=0$, (i.e., $k=0$), and then _assuming_ the truth of the theorem for all pairs $(p',q')$ with $p'-q'=k-1$, where $k \ge 1$, and where $(p',q')$ satisfy the required restrictions, the exact sequence shows that the theorem holds  for all pairs $(p,q)$  with $p-q=k$, where  $(p,q)$ also satisfy the required  restrictions.

Comment: It's not $k$ implies $k-1$. It's $k-1$ implies $k$.

Comment: The theorem has restrictions, so it's an "if ... then ..." type theorem. The case $(p,q)$ is the $k$ case. We don't assume the conclusion for that case. But we do assume that $(p,q)$ satisfies the "if ... " part. That's allowed because we're trying to prove an "if ... then ..." type result for the pair $(p,q)$. We're not using the inductive hypothesis for that assumption. We're not using the inductive hypothesis in any way for the case $(p,q)$. We're trying to _prove_ the truth of the theorem for the case $(p,q)$. Using $(p,q)$, we construct _another_ pair $(p',q')$.

Comment: I'll break down what I'm not understanding:  Assume that just $n \gt p$ and not $q \ge n$.  Then following all the steps from my posts previously and assuming that $H_n(X^p, X^q)$ is true inductively when $p-q = k-1$, we have $H_n(X^{q+1}, X^q)=0$.  How, by just assuming $n \gt p$ and not $q \ge n$ is true, do you prove that $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})=0$ is true?

Comment: No, $(p,q)$ is not the $k-1$ case. It's the $k$ case. The pair $(p',q')$ is the $k-1$ case. By the inductive hypothesis, we get to assume the truth for the pair $(p',q')$, provided we can show the restrictions are met. We _don't_ assume the $(p,q)$ case is true. We _prove_ it's true, based on the assumed truth for the case $(p',q')$. Look at my definition of $(p',q')$ and look at the RHS of the exact sequence.

Comment: You asked "How, by just assuming $n>p$ and not $q \ge n$ is true, do you prove that $H_n(X^p,X^{q+1})=0$ is true?". But that's not the assumption. We're assuming $n >p\;\;$OR$\;\;q \ge n$,

Comment: If we're assuming that $n \gt p$ OR $q \gt n$, then doesn't that mean:  either one is true and not the other, or both is true?  This is the definition of an OR statement that is used by logic:  if $A$ or $B$ is true, then $A$ is true, $B$ is true, or $A$ and $B$ is true.

Comment: Right, it's an inclusive or. At least one of them must be true. If you look at my proof, I considered two cases. I didn't assume no overlap (although in fact, the other restriction $p-q \ge 0$ actually bars overlap.

Comment: Then by assuming that $n \gt p$ is true and it is not the case that $q \ge n$ is true, how would you show that $H_n(X^p, X^{q+1})=0$ is true?

Comment: We show that if $n > p$, the the pair $(p',q')$ satisfies the required restrictions,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64080/discussion-between-oliver-g-and-quasi).